# Can I use specialized template without the primary template in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I tried this but this shows an error

```cpp
template<>
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

But when I write the below code it works fine

```cpp
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}
template<>
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Specialization only makes sense when you have something to specialize - i.e. the primary template.

Comment: Why would you want that anyway - if you just want an `add` function that takes 2 `int`s why not use a regular function ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your example. Did you try `template<> int add(int a,int b){ return a+b; }` without having `template<typename T>T add(T a,T b){return a+b;}`? In that case I'd like to ask why you need this and what you've expected to happen? What should happen when you specialize a template that doesn't exist?

Comment: You can't specialize anything which is not at least declared in general case. Anyway why you need a template at all in this case? Classic old fashioned overload does the job.

Comment: Dupe: [C++ template specialization without default function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629406/c-template-specialization-without-default-function)

Answer (score 3):

You need a primary template *declaration*, otherwise the compiler wouldn't know what part of the function would be templated. But you don't need to provide a primary *definition*. So you can do:

```
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b);

template<>
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to declare template function as deleted `template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b) = delete;` to get compilation error on instantiation instead of linker error.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use specialized template without the primary template in c++

No, specialization by definition can't exist without the primary template. We need a primary template so that we can specialize(either explicitly or partially) it for some(or all) template parameters.